# How do I make a complex Division operation pull back a decimal, rather than a full number?

Tags: c#, math, decimal, division

I'm trying to get a variable to equal

```
((65536) / (8200 - (encounter * 200)) / 65536) * 100
```

But it always gives me back '0'. I assume it's because it is rounding down. How would I make it so this operation gives me back the decimal that it is actually processing?

**Note** the 'encounter' variable ranges between 1 and 40 during the process of the operation.

Comment: Use `decimal` instead of `int`.

Comment: At no point in my code am I using 'int'. Everything is double.

Comment: You're using `65536` or `8200` which are `int`s implicitly. If they are actually  variables show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast it to double, like this:

((65536) / (8200 - ((decimal)encounter * 200)) / 65536) * 100

Comment: This worked. You're a beautiful man. I hadn't even thought of that.  Thanks a million.

Comment: Welcome, it always happen :)

Comment: Dependent on what the return type that you want.